# Drupal Commerce: Number of a sales per product

Tags: 7, commerce

How can I find the number of sales for a particular product in Drupal commerce?

Answer (score 2):

With this view I solved: https://www.drupal.org/node/1292104#comment-8524109
Just import it and play around for get what you want.

Comment: Thanks mate, the view worked. My requirement has been to list down all the products sold, just added one more filter criteria where commerce_order_status = invoiced.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Commerce Reporting](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_reports) module and get a lot of other relevant shop stats

> This module provides a reporting system for [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal_commerce).