# how to display sales volume for a product or a product variation in drupal commerce?

Tags: commerce

I need to display number of sales for a product or a product variation in product list. But I cannot find a decent way to go.
Can I count order numbers for a product or a product variation with their relation? How should I do?
I looked this thread [Drupal Commerce: Number of a sales per product](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27435/drupal-commerce-number-of-a-sales-per-product), what he want is a view, but I need to display number of sales in product list.
I appreciate for any help or comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, We can use hook_entity_view. and we can read profiles\commerce_kickstart\modules\contrib\commerce\modules\product_reference\commerce_product_reference.module for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://drupal.org/project/commerce_reports and edit your product list View to do what it does in its product sales report.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I want is to dislay sales volume in product list to customers, so they can make a decision(buy or not).

Comment: You'd still use the same approach. Commerce Reports is built using Views - your product list will be built using Views. Voila!

Comment: Thanks for your time, Ryan. I installed and enabled the commerce_reports, but EntityFieldQueryException raised: "EntityFieldQueryException: Unknown field: commerce_stock in EntityFieldQuery->addFieldCondition() (line 779 of D:\xampp\htdocs\commerce\includes\entity.inc).", my module versions: commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.19, commerce_reports-7.x-4.0-beta1.tar.gz, views_date_format_sql-7.x-3.1.tar.gz, charts-7.x-2.0-rc1.tar.gz, commerce_stock-7.x-2.0.tar.gz. but I guess I only need to study the code of Commerce reports, right?